# Prevent frontend form button redirecting to admin-post.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want a button click to trigger a function before page load. I have added `global $current_user;` to the template. I am working on a local setup.

The form I have on my `page.php` is:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send_user_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user-id" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" />
    <button class="send-id" type="submit">Send ID</button>
</form>
```

The function I use is as follows and works perfectly.

```
function post_user_id() {
    // Some Code
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_send_user_id', 'post_user_id' );
add_action( 'admin_post_send_user_id', 'post_user_id' );
```

The only problem I have is that after the button click the page redirects to `http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-post.php`. I would like the form to submit the details, run the function and refresh the page.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can remove the submit type from the button and then handle it's click event through your code. Send the form data by AJAX then refresh the current page by javascript.

Comment: Thank @AmitKumar. Worked Perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the action from the form tag, then your form will redirect to the same page,right.
now you have to define an if condition on the top like that:

```
if(isset[$_POST["submit"]{  //define a name for submit button
  //do whatever you wanted to do here i.e call a function.
  header('location:define your location where you wants this page to be redirected');
  }
```